# Can I make a PHP "macro" (like #define) to supply parameters for function calls?

Tags: php, macros

The parameters that I am talking about are `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` - those of the caller of the function, so that the function can use them in error reporting.

Let's say that I have two files and line 100 of file_1.php calls `my_func()` in file_2.php

I'd like to make that call `my_func(__FILE__, __LINE__)` so that if `my_func` encounters an error it can report it against file_1.php at line 100.

I do that since there are hundreds of calls to `my_func` and reporting the error to be in my_func() itself might not be informative (unless I dump the stack). And I don't want to have to manually type those two parameters a few hundred times.

In C I would do something like `#define MY_FUNC my_func(__FILE, __LINE)`  - can I do something similar in PHP?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can replicate C-like macros with the help of source file re-writing.

Write file `macro.php`:

```
<?php

$name = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$name = preg_replace('#\/#mui', '', $name);

$file = file_get_contents($name);

// get defined macros
preg_match_all('#\#macro\h+(\w+)\h+(.*)$#mui', $file, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach ($matches as $m) {
    // delete macro definition
    $file = str_replace($m[0], '', $file);
    // substitute macro => value
    $file = str_replace($m[1], $m[2], $file);
}

// save processed file
$new_name = '/var/tmp/' . $name . '.pr';
file_put_contents($new_name, $file);

include_once $new_name;
exit;
```

Now with such tool, usage is simple:

```
<?php

include_once "macro.php";

#macro DEBUG_INFO ;echo('<b>  DEBUG_INFO: __FILE__ : ' . __FILE__ . ';__LINE__ : ' . __LINE__ . '</b>')

echo '<br>'.(1/2); DEBUG_INFO;
echo '<br>'.(1/0); DEBUG_INFO;
echo '<br>'.(0/0); DEBUG_INFO;
```

When executed outputs:

> 0.5 DEBUG_INFO: **FILE** : /var/tmp/test.php.pr;**LINE** : 7
>
> INF DEBUG_INFO: **FILE** : /var/tmp/test.php.pr;**LINE** : 8
>
> NAN DEBUG_INFO: **FILE** : /var/tmp/test.php.pr;**LINE** : 9

I have strong C background and always missed C-like macros in PHP. But hopefully we can inject some sort of replacement for it.

Answer (score 15):

Unfortunately, PHP does not have any kind of macros. You could implement these yourself by running a command line tool like `sed` over some input to insert macros, but that is error prone and a bit sloppy.

To do what you want to do, you might consider the [debug_backtrace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) function.

Comment: 7 or 8 years later, I found this question again & thought that I would say that I use a combination of  Mojtab's answer for exceptions, adn backtrace as suggested here

Answer (score 3):

Nope. Use a stack trace: [debug_backtrace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php). You can retrieve the file and line of the caller, by simply looking at the second row in the returned array.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no C like Macros in PHP.

reading a debug_backtrace is tricky and I don't like that.

What I would like to throw an exception at error points then exception object it self contains the stack trace as well as the line number and file it's coming from.

```
catch (Exception $e)
{
   $errorMessage  = $e->getMessage() . " LINE: " .$e->getLine(). " FILE: " . $e->getFile();
}
```

Comment: Checkout this lib https://www.sitepoint.com/php-macros-for-fun-and-profit/

Comment: Wouldn't that give the line number of the exception handler, rather than the line which threw the exception?